# Spring Security how to ensure headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have Spring security config where I create `AuthenticationWebFilter` for specific endpoint.
In my case lets say its `/api/login`. For this endpoint I want to authenticate user with Basic usr/pass authentication. Any other endpoint should be freely availbale with no auth.

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .authorizeExchange()
          .and()
          .addFilterAt(buildUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
          .authorizeExchange()
          .anyExchange()
          .permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }

    private AuthenticationWebFilter buildUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
        UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(applicationUserService);
        authManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        AuthenticationWebFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("api/login"));
        return usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    }
```

I also have LoginController to handle login with `AuthenticatedPinciple`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LoginController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Mono<Map<String, Object>> login(@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<AuthenticatedUser> user) {
        ....
    }

}
```

Log-in with correct or incorrect credentials work fine as long as `Authorization` header is present and valid.

**The problem:**

If I try to POST to this endpoint with corrupted or no `Authorization` header at all, I want to send back 400 BAD_REQUEST, with preferably custom body, saying 'Invalid auth token' or w/e. I thought Springs AuthenticationWebFilter would take care of that. I was worng, instead it simply propagates null as AuthenticationPrinciple to LoginController where it crashes with 500 error. Not even an empty mono, but a null.

**Question:**
What would be the best way to ensure proper `Authorization` header is present when request is sent to '/api/login', and if not send back proper 400 response and not execute Controller mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The best proper way is to use the built in basic authentication functionality in spring security. You dont need to create your own filter, `httpBasic` is already available in spring security.

[http security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-httpsecurity)

if you wish to apply security to only certain endpoints you can define this using `antMatchers`.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .antMatchers("/api/login")
            .authenticated()
        )
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
}
```